# copying *.dat from different directories to a mirror directory

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a directory with the following structure:

```
C:\Directory1\
      sub1\
      sub2\
      sub3\
      somefilename.txt
      someotherfile.txt
```

Inside each `sub*\` there are `.dat` files that I need to copy to another directory mirroring along the way the directory name where they were found. So if I find `C:\Directory1\sub2\file.dat` I would copy that into `C:\mirror\sub2\file.dat` and so on.

I tried several combinations of things similar to

```
for /R %SRC_DIR% %%f in (*.dat) do copy "%%f" %BACKUP_DIR%\%%~nf%%~xf
```

(please note this is just an example of code I was playing with, i *know* it doesn't work)

anyway, after trying to a couple of day I still don't know how to do it. Any chance of help?
Code is appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set SourceDir=c:\source\dir
set TargetDir=d:\target\path
set FileMask=*.cpp

for /r "%SourceDir%" %%F in (%FileMask%) do (
    call :ReplacePrefix target_path "%%~F" "%SourceDir%" "%TargetDir%"
    call :CopyFile "%%~F" "!target_path!"
)

endlocal
goto :EOF


:CopyFile %1=source_path %2=target_path
    mkdir %~dp2
    copy %1 %2
    goto :EOF


:ReplacePrefix %1=result_var_name %2=string %3=replace_what %4=replace_with
    rem a question mark is prepended to ensure matching only at the beginning of the string
    set rp_value=?%~2
    call :DoIt "set %1=%%rp_value:?%~3=%~4%%"
    goto :EOF


:DoIt %1=cmd
    %~1
    goto :EOF
```

Keep in mind though that it can break if paths contain unusual characters (such as `=` and some others which I can't remember now).

Comment: Thanks. This is what happened when I run the script (after changing the directories and *.cpp to *.dat). It creates a mirror of each directory on C:\ but each directory is created on C:, not inside each other and it disregards TargetDir when creating the dirs. Finally it copies the .dat file to TargetDir without creating the mirror dirs inside TargetDir

Comment: @Mr Aleph - what was the problem? I based this post on a script I use without problems (though I edited it slightly before posting). So I'm curious as to what problem may be quietly lurking on my path :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following XCOPY command:

```
   xcopy "c:\directory1\*.dat" "c:\mirror\" /s /v /c /y
```

If you do not want to see the filenames displayed on the screen add '**/q**' to the list of options.

The '**/s**' will copy files from subfolders. If the subfolders don't already exist they will be created.

The '**/v**' forces verification. Not necessary but it's nice to have that peace of mind.

The '**/c**' forces XCOPY to continue with the rest of the files if it encounters any problems - in other words, your batch file won't halt abruptly with only '*some*' of your files copied. XCOPY will copy all that it can.

The '**/y**' suppresses prompting to overwrite an existing file.